# When we use k-means clustering with Light GBM, comparing with Random Forest

Tags: regression, clustering, random-forest, k-means, lightgbm

I am developping the prediction model with many parameters.

As I was not satisfied by the performance of Random Forest Regression, I tried to use

k-means clustering to regroup the similar variable and applied LIGHT GBM to each cluster.

It improved 16% in terms of RMSE and I was happy.

However, I cannot understand how it can improve the perforamnce because the basic idea of random forest is very similar to k-means clustering.

We make a branch considering the relation between variables when we use tree algorithm.

K-means make a cluster in terms of distance between each variable.

So, probably Random Forest did the similar thing with K-means.

Can you explain how can k-means-lightGBM improve the performance comparing with RF ?

Comment: Have you compared the performance of lightGBM to RF without k-means? What is this RMSE based on? Test set?

Comment: It can depend very strongly on the specific data what approach is better. I have run some experiments with k-means in regression (similar to what you did), and I have seen both it failing badly and working quite well. There is no general reason why it's better because it isn't *generally* better, however if the regression structure happens to be perfectly in line with the approach, it will be very good of course. (This should also hold for the specific combination with Light GBM.)

Comment: A statement like "random forest does  a similar thing to k-means" is very imprecise. Sure there are connections but there are also differences, and in specific examples they can be quite different, as k-means tries to keep within-cluster distances low generally whereas random forest is rather flexible in that respect.

Comment: @user2974951
Yes and it gave me a quite same performance (RMSE = 0.25 for RF and 0.245 for LGBM) and it is based on test set .